# How to use an object as a mask in HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm tying to recreate the effect in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showcasing the desired effect]

The purple circles (bubbles) will be moving around the screen and when the hover over the header, the are supposed to "reverse" the colors of the header under them, purple to white, white to black so that they are visible.

I think that in order to achieve this effect, the bubbles would need to act as a mask that is sitting between two layers of headers, one with "dark" other with "light" colors like this:

```
<dark header layer>
<bubbles>
<light header layer>
```

The dark header layer would have the lowest z-index and the light header the highest. Bubbles would than make it so, that only the part of light header in its frame is displayed. Any idea, similar problems etc. that would help me achieve this effect?

Comment: I think this is close to what you'd like to achieve:  https://codepen.io/kartikth40/pen/XWMOReZ. a quick google search brought it up.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `mix-blend-mode: difference;`.

[These](https://dev.to/kaos/dynamic-text-effects-with-css-mix-blend-mode-242a) [articles](https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/) give you a sense of what it can do.

Comment: Thanks, I already did read about this prior to posting the question, but I wasn't getting the desired effect. I managed to achieved what I wanted by rewriting the code ( codepen.io/kartikth40/pen/XWMOReZ ) provided by 'beerwin' in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

As provided by @beerwin, this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kartikth40/pen/XWMOReZ) had a very similar effect. It works by using the CSS `mask-image` property, which is being passed a radial gradient as an argument instead of an image. Than later in JS we can make the gradient move by modifying its `--x` and `--y` variables